# What is the best practice in linking pages/ loading javascripts in jquery mobile with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

My phonegap project is having multiple html's(more than 4) with some single-paged and multi-paged. 
When I move around pages, sometimes javascript breaks. maybe I am linking pages wrong... i've been googling..and got so many different answers.

- some say to include all the same heads' because .js won't load by ajax-type page loads
- some talk about app.initialize(); some talk about 'pageinit'. some recommends to use onload(); in body tag. some say pageshow: function(){}.
- some talk about .Deferred()/ $.when(deviceReadyDeferred,jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);
  **so many ways to initialize!**

**WHAT IS THE BEST PRACTICE IN INCLUDING JS FILES?**

Also, there are so many ways to link pages.

- i guess if an anchor leads to multi-paged html, use data-rel='external' is good practice. but some say data-dom-cache="true". some say $.mobile.changePage();

**WHAT IS THE BEST PRACTICE IN LINKING PAGES?**

- from single-paged .html --> multi-paged .html
- from multi-paged .html --> single-paged .html
- from single-paged .html --> single-paged .html
- from multi-paged .html --> multi-paged .html

can you give me a good foundation tutorial? or links to one of them? 
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my method.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
    <link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">

  </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var pagesHistory = [];
var currentPage = {};
var path = "";

function init(){

    $("body").load(path + "pages/ListPage.html", function(){
        $.getScript(path + "js/ListPage.js", function() {
            if (currentPage.init) {
                currentPage.init();
            }
        });
    });

}
```

ListPage.js

```
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function(){
    console.log("ListPage :: init");
};

currentPage.loadPage = function(pageIndex){
    console.log("ListPage :: loadPage :: pageIndex: " + pageIndex);
    $("body").load(path + "pages/" + pageIndex + ".html");
    $.getScript(path + "js/" + pageIndex +".js", function() {
        if (currentPage.init) {
            currentPage.init();
        }
    });
};
```

ListPage.html

```
<script>
    $.getScript(path + "js/ListPage.js");
</script>

<header class="bar bar-nav">
    <button id="LoadAddButton" class="btn pull-right" onclick="currentPage.loadPage('AddPage');">Load Add.html</button>
    <h1 class="title">ListPage</h1>
</header>

<div class="content">
<div class="content-padded">
    <button id="LoadDetailButton" class="btn btn-positive btn-block" onclick="currentPage.loadPage('DetailPage');">Load Detail.html</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need more clarification about this navigation.

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/15/simple-hybrid-mobile-app-using-cordova-and-ratchet-2-complete/

Comment: \what is the advantage of forming pages this way? i currently have 5 html pages.. using php, socket etc.. would u recommend me to recreate my project this way?? i am new to phonegap and im not quiet sure how to form my page navigation logic.. and urs seems nice

Comment: yes my friend. for php part you can create as REST API. even 1000 html pages no issues.

Comment: Im applying my codes to ur basic set up.. but css isn't being loaded.
for instance: index.html->ListPage.html works but css file doesn't follow. 
Even if i include all .css links in index.html head, after moving onto ListPage.html , css isn't applied. do u have any idea why?

Comment: can you update in your question? I want to see your latest code.

Comment: yes thank you for ur help by the way! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807740/getscript-and-css-issue-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Not important when you load your pages. Because all of your html files are included your app package.
I've used jQuery Mobile like the following;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css">

    <script src="js/dependencies/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dependencies/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dependencies/ejs.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   <div data-role="page" id="page-homepage" class="my-page" data-theme="b">
       <div data-role="header" class="div-header">
           // some header contents
       </div>
       <div role="main" class="ui-content">
           // some contents
       </div>
   </div>
   .
   .
   <div data-role="page" id="page-login" class="my-page" data-theme="b">
       <div role="main" class="ui-content">
           // login contents
       </div>
   </div>
   .
   .
   <script>

        /* jQuery Mobile pagecontainer change function's options */
        var changePageOptions = {
            transition: 'none',
            changeHash: true,
            reverse: true,
            showLoadMsg: true
        };   

        $("#btn-page-login").on("tap", function() {
            $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#page-login', changePageOptions);
        });

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```